# Compiling Vaadin widgetset with Gradle

Tags: gradle, gwt, widget, vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to compile a Vaadin 7.6.2 project using Gradle, but I'm getting an error compiling the widgetset.

I'm using `1.1.11` version of `fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin` plugin. The `AppWidgetset.gwt.xml` file is located in `src/main/resources` folder.

Looking at the logfile, it seems that the problem is related with `v-leaflet`module:

```
...
[INFO] Compiling module AppWidgetset
[INFO] Tracing compile failure path for type 'org.vaadin.addon.leaflet.client.LeafletRectangleConnector'
[ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.vaadin.addon/v-leaflet/1.0.0-rc2/904f6ddbeebaa8136472941911bc214bebeb1dc5/v-leaflet-1.0.0-rc2.jar!/org/vaadin/addon/leaflet/client/LeafletRectangleConnector.java'
[ERROR] Line 17: No source code is available for type org.peimari.gleaflet.client.Layer; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 22: No source code is available for type org.peimari.gleaflet.client.Polygon; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 22: No source code is available for type org.peimari.gleaflet.client.PolylineOptions; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 26: No source code is available for type org.peimari.gleaflet.client.LatLngBounds; did you forget to inherit a required module?
...
```

Here is the content of build.gradle (vaadin related sections):

```
plugins {
   ...
   id "fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin" version "1.1.11"
}
...

dependencies {
...
compile group: 'com.vaadin', name: 'vaadin-spring-boot-starter', version:'1.0.0'
compile group: 'org.vaadin.spring.extensions', name: 'vaadin-spring-ext-core', version:'0.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.vaadin.spring.extensions', name: 'vaadin-spring-ext-boot', version:'0.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.vaadin.spring.extensions', name: 'vaadin-spring-ext-security', version:'0.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.vaadin.spring.addons', name: 'vaadin-spring-addon-i18n', version:'0.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.vaadin.spring.addons', name: 'vaadin-spring-addon-eventbus', version:'0.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.vaadin', name: 'viritin', version:'1.44'

compile group: 'org.vaadin.addon', name: 'v-leaflet', version:'1.0.0-rc2'

compile(group: 'org.vaadin.addons', name: 'v-leaflet-markercluster', version:'1.0.0-b2') {
    exclude(group: 'org.vaadin.addon', module: 'v-leaflet')
}
compile(group: 'org.vaadin.addon', name: 'v-leaflet-heat', version:'0.4') {
    exclude(group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple')
    exclude(group: 'org.vaadin.addon', module: 'v-leaflet')
}

compile group: 'org.vaadin.addons', name: 'filteringtable', version:'0.9.15.v7'
compile group: 'com.vaadin.addon', name: 'vaadin-charts', version:'3.0.0'
compile group: 'com.vaadin.addon', name: 'vaadin-context-menu', version:'0.7.2'
compile group: 'org.vaadin.addons', name: 'vaadin-sliderpanel', version:'1.3.0'
compile group: 'eu.maxschuster', name: 'vaadin-autocompletetextfield', version:'1.0-alpha-4'
compile group: 'com.vaadin.addon', name: 'tableexport-for-vaadin', version:'1.6.2'
compile group: 'org.vaadin.teemu', name: 'switch', version:'2.0.3'
...
}
...

vaadin {  
   version '7.6.2'
}
```

I don't know why the error occurs, previously I was using maven and everything was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace it looks like the v-leaflet addon is depending on g-leaflet which doesn't appear to be on your classpath.

You could try adding

```
compile group: 'org.peimari', name: 'g-leaflet', version: '1.0.4'
```

to your build and see if it helps.